# Meta content type

Tags: 8, entities

Drupal core allows creating content types. I wish to have several different content types, all with the same structure.

For example:

- Food
- Italian food
- Sicilian food

Each content type would share the same structure; if I add, or remove, a field the change should be reflected to each content type.

The reason I seek to use a parent content type, instead of using a taxonomy term field is that I could then adjust blocks to each child content type (for example a block about food in general, a block about general Italian food, a block about Sicilian food).

Is there a core way to do that?

Comment: This sounds like taxonomy, food is food, food has subtypes (terms).

Comment: Short and sweet, but: no, there's no way to do that in core. There's no concept of inheritance/template/meta-structure as you're describing for entity types

Comment: This will not help you manage the addition/deletion of fields, but there are entity bundle types, which are useful if you already created several content types with the same set of fields and want to share code among them: https://www.drupal.org/node/3191609

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [Entity Inherit](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_inherit) module which will allows entities to inherit certain fields from another entity.

> **How it works**
>
> You tell Entity Inherit, in /admin/config/entity_inherit
> which fields are used to define an entity’s parent. For example you
> might create an entity reference field named
> field_entity_inherit_parent for this purpose.
>
> Then, every time any entity is modified:
>
> If other entities inherit from it, and have the same fields, and the
> child’s field has the same values as the parent field before it was
> changed, the “child” entities’ fields are updated to reflect the
> parent entity’s new value.